# Is threre any way to convert xcarchive to xcodeworkspace?

Tags: xcode, recover, xcarchive

my xcode project after one month developing unexpectedly has been removed ,because of a silly mistake ,unfortunately i don't have any backup!
everything i have is an archived file : myprojectname.xcarchive
is there any way to de-compile it extract some of classes or codes?
any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this is not possible because the archive does not contain your app's source code.  You can look inside a xcarchive simply by control-clicking it in the Finder and choosing “Show Package Contents”.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to help, but I am going to give a try!!

Please correct me if I am wrong, since I am new to iOS development.

You can first generate IPA out of the xcarchive using a developer profile and install it in a device. Then you can run the safari simulator to check the resource files used in the application. Though you cannot import all the resource files from there, this may help you avoid the unnecessary need to write everything from the scratch. (It will save you a lot of pain).